# Applying or removing a filter to an Access query field with a checkbox

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, filter

I'm trying to apply a filter to a [Billed] column of a query, which is a yes/no field, by using a checkbox on a form. 

 HERE'S THE BACKSTORY:  
I have a timesheet table (tblTimesheet) which contains information like [Date], [Job Number], [Employee], [Hours], [Billed], etc. When it's time to invoice for a specific job number, I generate a report for the job, then check the box in the [Billed] column for each record included in the invoice.

I queried tblTimesheet, then based frmJobTime on that query. I placed an unbound textbox on the form in order to filter the report (which is also based on the query). SO, the criteria under [Job Number] in the query looks like this:
[Forms]![frmJobTime]![txtJobNum] 

It works PERFECTLY.

 HERE'S THE ACTUAL PROBLEM:
  I want to add a similar filter to the [Billed] column by adding a checkbox to frmJobTime. In a perfect world, checking the box would mean that the report only displays UNBILLED records for the job, and an unchecked box would mean that ALL records, both billed AND unbilled, appear in the report. I cannot get this to work.
I have Googled this a million different ways and have not come any closer to figuring out how to do this. I even changed my tactic to using a textbox (like I did for [Job Number]) so that you could filter for unchecked records by typing "False" on the form. That works, but if the textbox is left empty (which I thought meant that NO filter would be applied), no records at all appear in the report. I've also tried writing IIf() statements in the criteria, but I must be writing the formula incorrectly. 

EDIT: (OK, let's try this again) Here's the SQL:

SELECT tblTimesheet.Date, tblTimesheet.[Job Number], tblTimesheet.Expense, tblTimesheet.[Miles Traveled], tblTimesheet.[Project Description], tblTimesheet.Employee, tblTimesheet.Hours, tblTimesheet.[Billed?], tblTimesheet.[Hourly Total], tblTimesheet.[Mileage Total], tblTimesheet.[GRAND TOTAL], tblTimesheet.Rate
FROM tblTimesheet
WHERE (((tblTimesheet.[Job Number]) Like " * " & [Forms]![frmJobTimeFilter]![txtJobNum] & " * ") AND ((tblTimesheet.[Billed?])=[Forms]![frmJobTimeFilter]![chkUnbilledFilter]));

 
Doing it this way returns either all true values (if I check the box) or all false values (unchecked box). How do I create the option to view ALL records?

Is there a better way to go about doing this? Please help!! Replies in layman's terms would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please EDIT your post with the current query, so we could give you a proper solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, @PaulFrancis, I don't know what you mean by that. But I can't post an image  of my query builder or attach a file, if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: You can put a query into SQL view and can get your written query directly from there.

Comment: I would just edit your main post and put it in there.  You can actually format it in there. Comments not so much.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Newd. The question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a column in your DB to give back 0 if check box is unchecked and 1 if checked... then you can easily run your query where field = 1.

Comment: wouldn't that still only be giving me either only True values or only False values?

Answer (score 0):

http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/905256-iif-statements-criteria-query-false-value-returning-all-records

This is where I found the answer, and here is my new SQL:

SELECT tblTimesheet.Date, tblTimesheet.[Job Number], tblTimesheet.Expense, tblTimesheet.[Miles Traveled], tblTimesheet.[Project Description], tblTimesheet.Employee, tblTimesheet.Hours, tblTimesheet.[Billed?], tblTimesheet.[Hourly Total], tblTimesheet.[Mileage Total], tblTimesheet.[GRAND TOTAL], tblTimesheet.Rate
FROM tblTimesheet
WHERE (((tblTimesheet.[Job Number]) Like " * " & [Forms]![frmJobTimeFilter]![txtJobNum] & " * ") AND ((tblTimesheet.[Billed?]) Like IIf([Forms]![frmJobTimeFilter]![chkUnbilledFilter]=True,False,"*")));

Now, I check the box (labeled "View unbilled time only") and the report generated will only display UNBILLED time. If the box is unchecked, all values appear. 
THANK YOU, GOOGLE!